# Database level encryption in SQL Server 2008 Express edition 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

Database level encryption in SQL Server 2008 Express - is it possible? 
If it is possible - then how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search would have easily revealed the [Features supported by the editions of SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.100%29.aspx) web page.

This lists all the features and which editions support them. In the **Security** section, you will see that none of the Express editions support any database encryption.

So no - database encryption is **not** possible with the Express editions.